# request to nodejs proxy: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: node.js, cross-domain

In my web app project, I came across a cross domain issue. The back-end API was deployed to the server, which providing the IP and port(We can assume the back-end API works well). And I am working on the front-end side, and still in the local development stage. So there is cross domain issue.

so I used a nodejs proxy and try to overcome the cross domain issue. For the nodejs proxy part, I am not the expert on that. Just get it from my teammates, who meet the same issue before.

So in my client side js code, I use `axios` library to send http request to the nodejs proxy as following:

```
  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/service/delete/v1?id=5').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And the nodejs proxy will replace the `127.0.0.1:8888` part with the real API's IP and port, and send the request. That's my understanding about it.

so I run the nodejs  proxy, which is listening on port 8888, and run my frond-end  code in another console. But when I send the above mentioned request. I got the error as following:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/service/delete/v1?id=5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?f777:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?14ed:87)
```

and I debug the error deeper in the chrome devtool, and find the `Provisional headers are shown` in the header as following

[image]

I searched some previous article about this issue.It's said that the potential reason is the request is blocked.

But I can send other HTTP request successfully to other third party APIs. For example my mock data service Mockarro as following:

```
     const key = 'mykeyxxx';
     const url = `http://www.mockaroo.com/api/generate.json?schema=firstapis&key=${key}`;
     axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
     });
```

So my the previous request is blocked. I am very confused. My guess is the issue is from the  nodejs proxy part? Right?